# How to read multiple inputs from user for array manipulation in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

How do i take multiple inputs from user and print the result as per the input.
For example in the below codec i want to take multiple `11 digit number` from user and print the result Y or N  for each input by user as per the given if else condition.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 11 digit  number");
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    int[] a=new int[12];
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        a[i] = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));  
    }

    int result = a[0] + a[1] *3+ a[2] * 7 + a[3]*9 + a[4] + a[5] * 3 + a[6] * 7 + a[7] * 9 + a[8] + a[9] * 3 + a[10];
    if(result%10==0){
        System.out.println("Y");
        }
    else{
        System.out.println("N");
        }

   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read about while loops. Or in case the number of repetitions is fixed : simply write another enclosing for loop. Hint: can someone help isn't regarded a real question here.

Answer (score 0):

Please do something like below :

```
 Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter 11 digit number and press Q to quit");
        String number= scanner.nextLine();
        if(question.equals("Q")){
            break;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In condition you can put condition when to terminate the loop as mentioned in below ans.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

       while(sc.hasNextLine()){

       System.out.println(sc.nextLine());

      }
     }
```